# Removing gaps in data frame preserving pairs (R)

Tags: r

I have a very basic question in R but I can't seem to get it sorted.
I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
                 date      x                        y
    1 01/01/2003 00:00     17.04783                NA         
    2 02/01/2003 00:00     14.84500         10.117042                        
    3 03/01/2003 00:00     12.23636                NA          
    4 04/01/2003 00:00     12.62381                NA         
    5 05/01/2003 00:00           NA          4.516619         
    6 06/01/2003 00:00     12.93333                NA
```

I'm only interested in the cases where there is both an x value and a y value, i.e. in the above data im only interested in row 2.

How do i create a new data frame with only the cases that I'm interested in?
I need to preserve the date structure too, so the ideal data would look like this:

```
        date               x                        y
    1 01/01/2003 00:00     NA                      NA         
    2 02/01/2003 00:00     14.84500         10.117042                        
    3 03/01/2003 00:00     NA                      NA          
    4 04/01/2003 00:00     NA                      NA         
    5 05/01/2003 00:00     NA                      NA
    6 06/01/2003 00:00     NA                      NA
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pick out the rows where you want to keep the values with `complete.cases()`; then set everything but the date in the other rows to `NA`.

```
print(df)
#         date    result   result2
#1  2015-01-03 0.4179292        NA
#2  2015-01-05 0.5830931        NA
#3  2015-01-09 0.9207914 0.3846393
#4  2015-01-13        NA 0.4652525
#5  2015-01-17 0.1167908 0.6160894
#6  2015-01-23 0.7866672 0.8541210
#7  2015-01-27 0.8721665 0.8580503
#8  2015-01-29        NA        NA
#9  2015-02-01        NA 0.4687221
#10 2015-02-06        NA 0.2769060
#11 2015-02-11 0.6086726 0.3619493
#12 2015-02-17 0.7421181        NA

df[!complete.cases(df), -1] <- NA
print(df)
#         date    result   result2
#1  2015-01-03        NA        NA
#2  2015-01-05        NA        NA
#3  2015-01-09 0.9207914 0.3846393
#4  2015-01-13        NA        NA
#5  2015-01-17 0.1167908 0.6160894
#6  2015-01-23 0.7866672 0.8541210
#7  2015-01-27 0.8721665 0.8580503
#8  2015-01-29        NA        NA
#9  2015-02-01        NA        NA
#10 2015-02-06        NA        NA
#11 2015-02-11 0.6086726 0.3619493
#12 2015-02-17        NA        NA
```